# problems of use phpmyadmin to transfer data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two mysql database,now I want to trasnfer a whole table to the other database.

[image]

[image]

As you can see from the two pictures,the sequence of columns is different.
Do I need to adjust them to the same sequence?
Since there are some backend and frontend and remote servers need these data
to check whether a user can login or not.
And when I import the .sql data,phpmyadmin said the table name already exists,
so do I have to delete the origin table and import again or there is an alternative way?

//  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkxce.png
//  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzguG.png

Comment: You can re-arrange column orders easily in the PHPMyAdmin GUI

Comment: By the looks of the photos you have, the column order highlighted looks the same?